# how to use multer file uploading inside a function in node js

Tags: node.js, multer

```
var uuid = uuid.v1().toString();
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  'destination' : function(req,file,cb){
    if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'image/jpeg'){
        cb(null,'uploads/pics/');
    }
    else if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'video/mp4'){
        cb(null,'uploads/videos/');
    }
    else if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'image/png'){
        cb(null,'uploads/thumbs/');
    }
    else{
        res.send('400');
    }

  },
  'filename' : function(req,file,cb){

    if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'image/jpeg'){
        cb(null,uuid + '.jpg');
    }
    else if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'video/mp4'){
        cb(null,uuid + '.mp4');
    }
    else if(file.mimetype.toString() == 'image/png'){
        cb(null,uuid + '.png');
    }
    else{
        res.send('400');
    }
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage });

UserService.prototype.uploadMultimedia = function(req, res) {
//call upload ???
}
```

here i configure multer and now i want to call upload inside the upload media function. so any suggestions please?. i tried it following way but wasn't succes :

```
upload.any();
```

By the way UserService is defined early in the code. Now i just want to know how to call upload inside the function 'uploadMultimedia'

Comment: if you're using express, you'll want to reference upload within the app.post app.post funtion: `app.post('/getFileSize', upload.single("file"),(req, res) => {
    ....
})`, the '/getFileSize' path is what is referenced within the action URL in your front end HTML

Comment: yeah i know this BenWS. but here i have to use it inside this function. so is there any way to call it inside the function?

Comment: yeah i know this way BenWS. but here i want to use it inside this function. is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Expose this as a route in your routes file or `app.js`

```
app.post('/uploadMultimedia',upload.single('file'),UserService.prototype.uploadMultimedia);
```

Then you can easily access `req.file` in your function.